# Hot to use highcharts license key in our application

Tags: highcharts

Few days ago I bought a highchart's developer license but I am confused how should I use it in my application. any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The license is only as verification or to contact support/sales.
Do not put it anywhere in the project.

More information you can find at https://shop.highsoft.com/faq or if you have a specific questions try to contact with the [sales team](https://shop.highsoft.com/contact/).

> There is no mandatory license key associated with the software, and no
> activation is needed. The license is solely a legal document and
> consists of two parts: The Terms and Conditions and the License
> Statement. These documents are attached to the order confirmation
> email you received after the completion of your purchase.